# Fechas en Java, los valores no se corresponden

Tags: java

Estoy intentando convertir una fecha de un BJSON a un timestamp de java o por lo menos algo legible y fiable y ya lo retoco yo con java... el caso es que tengo esta fecha en BJSON del mongoDB

```
ISODate("2019-05-21T07:16:00.599Z")
```

Al obtener este resultado en Java me devuelve:

```
Tue May 21 09:16:00 CEST 2019
```

Ahora lo voy a cambiar para obtener el día mes y año ...

```
 DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu", Locale.US);
 ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(updateDate, dtf);
```

Estoy obteniendo:

```
2019-05-21T09:16+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

Parece ser que según java me está devolviendo las 09horas, y 16 minutos y 02 segundos como resultado final.
Sin embargo cuando me lo devolvía con `Tue May 21 09:16:00 CEST 2019`, los segundos eran 00.

¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: Tiene pinta que cuando las parseas no estas teniendo encuenta las zonas horarias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estás interpretando bien los datos:

```
ISODate("2019-05-21T07:16:00.599Z")
```

Este instante es "21 de mayo de 2019, a las 7:16 *hora Zulú*. Esto significa [UTC+0](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado), es decir, hora del meridiano de Greenwich (aunque ya no se dice así, es Tiempo Universal Coordinado). En España, al ser horario de verano (UTC +2), ese momento sería el mismo día pero a las 9:16 (hora local). Esta hora se ve reflejada en el segundo valor que pones:

```
Tue May 21 09:16:00 CEST 2019
```

CEST significa *Central Europe Summer Time* (Hora de verano en Europa Central).

El último valor es equivalente:

```
2019-05-21T09:16+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

Te dice que es el 21 de mayo (`2019-05-21`), a las 9 y 16 (`09:16`, se omiten los segundos), en CEST (`+02:00[Europe/Paris]`)

Comment: Entonces, ¿ todo es correcto ?

Comment: Sí, todos los valores mostrados representan el mismo momento